# Does Google's Speech-to-Text uses a Language model to improve the quality of output?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I have 2 questions related to Google's Speech-to-Text API (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text)

**a)** Does any one know if Google's Speech-to-Text API uses a language model (LM) on top of raw output to improve the quality of output by using the LM to correct the words which are wrong in the raw output

**b)** If it indeed uses a LM, how can I disable/turn it off so as to get the raw output with corrections?